# Html.Actionlink class

Tags: html, class

I have Html.Actionlink below

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add", "UpdateNote", "Notes", new { id = 0, type = (int)THOS.Utilities.Enumerations.Enumerations.Note.RelatedApplicationType.Law, appid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID, baseappid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID }, null)
```

How can i integrated below classes to Html.Actionlink ?

```
class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-edit"
```

I tried below however id did not work.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add", "UpdateNote", "Notes", new { id = 0, type = (int)THOS.Utilities.Enumerations.Enumerations.Note.RelatedApplicationType.Law, appid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID, baseappid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @class = "icon-edit" })
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all classes in a single `@class` attribute.

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", 
                 "UpdateNote", 
                 "Notes", 
                 new { id = 0, type = (int)THOS.Utilities.Enumerations.Enumerations.Note.RelatedApplicationType.Law, appid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID, baseappid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID }
                 new { @class = "btn btn-primary icon-edit"},
                 null)
```

Comment: what about <i class="icon-edit"> there is "i" ? can i integrated "i" to html actionlink ?

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/-Net-MVC-Html-ActionLink-tutorial-with-examples